# Python BeautifulSoup - find_all capture string surrounded by white space and a new line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following snippets of HTML which are part of a much larger HTML page:

```
<tr >
    <th class="left">
        <span tooltip haspopup="true" class="tip" title="A type of fruit">Oranges</span>:
    </th>
    <td class="reduce">
        Seven
    </td>
</tr>

<tr >
    <th class="left">
        Apples
    </th>
    <td>
        Three
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I execute the code:

```
soup.find_all(string='Oranges')
```

I get:

```
['Oranges']
```

Which is perfect.

However when I execute the code:

```
soup.find_all(string='Apples')
```

I get:

```
[]
```

Why isn't this working? I have a feeling it's to do with the whitespace and new line etc around the 'Apples' bit of the HTML code, however I can't work out to catch it. I've tried the below which have been fruitless.

```
soup.find_all(string='\n        Apples\n    ')

soup.find_all(string='        Apples    ')

soup.find_all(string='         Apples     ')
```

Would appreciate your help! Thanks.

P.s. I don't think it's important but ultimately I'm using a "findParent().fetchNextSiblings()[0].text.strip()" or similar to get the 'Seven' and 'Three' - which works in the former case but not in the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import re
...

soup.find_all(text = re.compile(r"Apples", re.IGNORECASE))
```